# Print a returned file from a function

Tags: python, function, return

I just want to print a file that is returned from a separate function:

```
def open_file():
    while True:
        try:
            filename = input("Input a file name: ")
            file=open(filename,'r')
            return file
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error: Enter a valid file.")
            continue
        else:
            break
open_file()
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

It's prompting for the file, and gives the error and re-promts when an invalid file is entered, but when a valid file is entered, it says that "file" is not defined. It's defined in the open_file function though, and is the returned value... So why doesn't it print?

Comment: You need to use your `return` statement to assign to a variable `file = open_file()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file` is the name of class object. You should use something else;
The problem in your code is that you don't save the return code from your function.

```
def open_file():
    while True:
            filename = input("Input a file name: ")
            try:
                f = open(filename,'r')
                return f
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Error: Enter a valid file.")
                continue

f = open_file()
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

You don't need to `else` clause, because you never reach it. You return from the function if there is no exception, and if there is - the else clause doesn't get executed anyway.

The **try … except** statement has an optional **else** clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is *useful for code that must be executed if the try clause* **does not raise an exception.**

You can do the same with more elegant way;

```
for line in open_file():
    print line
```

The behavior of iterating with a for loop on a **file** object iterates the file line-by-line.

Comment: Oh, so what is the class object of `file` in python 3? I still thinks its a bad idea to use this name, since it can be confusing.

Comment: In Python 3, files are derived from [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase). Eg, a text file is `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`, a binary file is `<class '_io.BufferedReader'>` or `<class '_io.BufferedWriter'>`. Also see `io.RawIOBase`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `file` as a variable. It is a builtin type, like `int` or `str`. To print the file returned from `open_file`, you need to use the `file.readlines()` function:

```
f = open_file()
for line in f.readlines():
    print(line)
```

And an improvement for your `open_file` function:

```
def open_file():
    while True:
        try:
            return open(raw_input("Enter a file name: "), 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error: Enter a valid file name.")
```

Answer (score 0):

`file` is a **local** variable of your `open_file` function. It is therefore not available outside of the function. You should assign asign the return value:

```
def open_file():
    while True:
        try:
            # ...
            return file
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # ...
        # no break needed; the return statement ends the function


file = open_file()
for line in file:
    print(line)
```